# Capturando valores de um Select para o Controller - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Bom dia Galerinha, tudo beleza?

Estou começando com o `codeigniter` e no meio desse processo me deparei com uma dúvida sobre a função `select`. Bom, a minha dúvida é retornar o `value` desse select para o meu `controller`, para eu poder fazer uma verificação a partir do `value`.
Eu tenho um gráfico e preciso controlar as informações dele pelo meu `select`.
Como se o meu `select` virasse um `button`, então quando eu escolhesse a opção automaticamente as informações do gráfico mudariam.

```css
select{

    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    
    background-position: 100% center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    line-height: normal;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 2.3125rem; 
    border-radius: 1px rgb(189, 189, 189) !important;
    min-width: 20px !important;
    
    
    
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="menuselect">
                     <option>Only me</option>
                     <option>Team</option>
                  </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select class="form-control" id="menuselect">
                 <option value="1">Only me</option>
                 <option value="2">Team</option>
              </select>
```

so colocar o value de cada option, e quando for relacionar esse valor no controller é só pegar pelo id do select, nesse caso é id="menuselect"

o value tbm pode receber algum id do controller...

Comment: Certo, só que minha dúvida é essa, como eu pego ele no controller? $this->input->post() ? ou set_select()?

Comment: olha php não é minha especialidade mas tenta o seguinte comando, $selectOption = $_POST['menuselect'];

Comment: Eu estou pelo codeigniter, fiz a chamada, porém não funciona, acho que devo transformar meu select em um "button" tipo o action do form.

Comment: dei uma pesquisada pra ter ajudar aqui, pessoal diz pra usar esse comando $variavel = $this->input->post("menuselect");, no caso vc precisa ter certeza que o select esta dentro de um form com http method sendo post

Comment: Fiz aqui, porém minha value não está sendo capturada.

ficou assim

Html:

´<form name="selectUser" id="selectUser" method="post" action="welcome/cliente">
                  <select class="form-control" onchange="document.getElementById('selectUser').submit()" >
                     <option value='<?php$_SESSION["nome"]?>'>Only me</option>
                     <option value="Diego">Team</option>
                  </select>
                  </form>´

meu controller inserir assim:

$nome = $this->input_post('selectUser');
echo $nome;

porém não retorna nada.

Comment: Consegui amigo! eu esqueci de declarar o name="selectUser" no meu <select>! Valeu pelo ajudar!

Comment: acredito que não esteja pegando porque vc não deu um id de referência para o select, o que deve estar chegando no controller é uma requisição vazia, experimenta colocar um name no select e da um nome pra ele e no controller tente capturar o name do select não o id, name do form, só pra constar tbm, faz um teste simples, no onchange colocar um alert e passa o value do select pra ver  o que ele retorna

Comment: perfeito! fico feliz em ajudar